# What does a Synth component do?

Tags: robots, biology, fallout

We know the component isn't needed for the android to live because Harkness had his removed, and we know it's not required to program the android because the recall code still worked with Harkness, so what does the android component do?

Comment: https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Synth_component